# width 100% causes horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I've created a page with HTML and CSS, the problem is horizontal scrollbar is showing up although as far as I've checked there is no element with width over 100% or inappropriate padding or margin.

here is the complete HTML and CSS code: https://jsfiddle.net/m11nsbag/9/

```
   @keyframes modalAnimation {
  from {
    top: 90vh;
  }
  to {
    top: 95vh;
    background-color: darkcyan;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px #747474;
  }
}

#headerImage {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: -10000000;
}

#main-nav>li {
  width: 9vw;
  height: 7vh;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 7vh;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: medium;
  z-index: 100;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

#main-nav {
  background-color: rgba(245, 255, 249, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 7vh;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  float: right;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

/*
#main-nav:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,129,129,1);
} */

#main-nav>li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(232, 255, 92);
}

#wall {
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -10;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#main-nav>li>a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.modalLayout {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modalLayout:target {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  z-index: 200;
}

.modal {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6% 1% 1.7% 1%;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 20vh;
  margin: 30vh 35vw;
  background-color: crimson;
  position: fixed;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px #484848;
}

.closeBtn {
  font-size: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25vh;
  right: 33vw;
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 5px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.mainPageButton>div {
  display: none;
}

.mainPageButton:hover>div {
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.mainPageButton>div>div {
  width: 15vw;
  height: 8vh;
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  color: #000;
  font-size: medium;
  float: top;
  border-bottom: black 1px solid;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 8vh;
}

.mainPageButton>div>div>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: medium;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.mainMenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 88vh;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-right: 1vw;
}

.mainMenu>div {
  width: 15vw;
  height: 10vh;
  border-bottom: black solid 2px;
  margin-bottom: 3vh;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all .3s;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 10vh;
}

.mainMenu>div:hover {
  width: 17vw;
  height: 12vh;
  background-color: #ffcfce;
}

.mainMenu>div>a {
  font-size: x-large;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.about {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: #94ffca;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 88vh;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  font-size: larger;
  padding: 1vw;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-left: 4px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.about:hover {
  transform: translate(5px);
  background-color: rgba(148, 255, 202, 0.5);
}

#modalcontainer {
  background-color: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.75);
  top: 80vh;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200%;
  z-index: -10;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
}

#modalswall {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 150vh;
  background-color: #0d213c;
  position: absolute;
  top: 85vh;
  right: 20vw;
  z-index: -5;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 25px grey;
  filter: opacity(90%);
}

.bodyModals {
  background-color: #acd7ff;
  top: 90vh;
  width: 35vw;
  height: 25vh;
  right: 28vw;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all .5s;
  margin-bottom: 10vh;
}

.bodyModals:hover {
  -webkit-animation: modalAnimation;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.bodyModals>p {
  padding: 1vw;
  font-size: large;
}

#wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 170vh;
  position: relative;
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 25vh;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #0d213c;
}

#footer>p {
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I think there maybe a padding or margin which I'm overlooking but I've been looking at it for several hours and tried almost anything.

thanks for your sincere help.

**Update:** I changed all the 100vw with 100% and the problem was fixed.

Comment: I'm not able to see the horizontal scroll bar. Are you talking about the one on the top.?

Comment: you padding 10px something with 100% width, check #footer class also #modalcontainer class

Comment: also 100vw is problematic...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does vw include the scrollbar as part of the viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551606/why-does-vw-include-the-scrollbar-as-part-of-the-viewport)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vertical scrollbars are included in `vw` units.
So when there's a vertical scrollbar, `100vw` is wider than the viewport (without scrollbars).

One suggestion is to change `#modalcontainer` to `width:100%` instead of `width:100vw`.

```css
@keyframes modalAnimation {
  from {
    top: 90vh;
  }
  to {
    top: 95vh;
    background-color: darkcyan;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px #747474;
  }
}

#headerImage {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: -10000000;
}

#main-nav>li {
  width: 9vw;
  height: 7vh;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 7vh;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: medium;
  z-index: 100;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

#main-nav {
  background-color: rgba(245, 255, 249, 0.5);
  width: 50%;
  height: 7vh;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  float: right;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}


/*
#main-nav:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,129,129,1);
} */

#main-nav>li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(232, 255, 92);
}

#wall {
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -10;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#main-nav>li>a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.modalLayout {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modalLayout:target {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  z-index: 200;
}

.modal {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6% 1% 1.7% 1%;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 20vh;
  margin: 30vh 35vw;
  background-color: crimson;
  position: fixed;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px #484848;
}

.closeBtn {
  font-size: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25vh;
  right: 33vw;
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 5px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.mainPageButton>div {
  display: none;
}

.mainPageButton:hover>div {
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.mainPageButton>div>div {
  width: 15vw;
  height: 8vh;
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  color: #000;
  font-size: medium;
  float: top;
  border-bottom: black 1px solid;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 8vh;
}

.mainPageButton>div>div>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: medium;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.mainMenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 88vh;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-right: 1vw;
}

.mainMenu>div {
  width: 15vw;
  height: 10vh;
  border-bottom: black solid 2px;
  margin-bottom: 3vh;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all .3s;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 10vh;
}

.mainMenu>div:hover {
  width: 17vw;
  height: 12vh;
  background-color: #ffcfce;
}

.mainMenu>div>a {
  font-size: x-large;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.about {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: #94ffca;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 88vh;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  font-size: larger;
  padding: 1vw;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-left: 4px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.about:hover {
  transform: translate(5px);
  background-color: rgba(148, 255, 202, 0.5);
}

#modalcontainer {
  background-color: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.75);
  top: 80vh;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  z-index: -10;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
}

#modalswall {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 150vh;
  background-color: #0d213c;
  position: absolute;
  top: 85vh;
  right: 20vw;
  z-index: -5;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 25px grey;
  filter: opacity(90%);
}

.bodyModals {
  background-color: #acd7ff;
  top: 90vh;
  width: 35vw;
  height: 25vh;
  right: 28vw;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all .5s;
  margin-bottom: 10vh;
}

.bodyModals:hover {
  -webkit-animation: modalAnimation;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.bodyModals>p {
  padding: 1vw;
  font-size: large;
}

#wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 170vh;
  position: relative;
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  min-height: 25vh;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #0d213c;
}

#footer>p {
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="main-nav">
  <li class="mainPageButton">
    <a href="#mainPageDropdownMenu"> </a>
    <div>
      <div>
        <a href="#"> </a>
      </div>

      <div>
        <a href="#"> </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#"> </a>
      </div>

      <div>
        <a href=""> </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#aboutMe"> </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#contactUS"> </a>
  </li>
</ul>


<img src="http://ghmahdi.ir/wp-content/uploads/header.jpg" id="headerImage">

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="aboutMe" class="modalLayout">
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="closeBtn"> × </a>
    </div>
    <div class="modal"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="contactUS" class="modalLayout">
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="closeBtn"> × </a>
    </div>
    <div class="modal"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="mainMenu">
    <div> <a href="#aboutModal"></a></div>
    <div><a href=""></a></div>
    <div><a href=""></a></div>
    <div><a href=""></a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="about"></div>
  <div id="modalswall"></div>
  <div class="bodyModals"> </div>
  <div class="bodyModals"></div>
  <div class="bodyModals"></div>
  <div id="modalcontainer">  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
```

For interest, also see:
[Bug 133271](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=133271)
[viewport units in case of 'overflow:auto'](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Jan/0616.html)