# px unit width resolution problem in screen

Tags: html, css

In this setup

```
<div class="a">

</div>
```

```
.a {
   width: 400px;
   height: 600px;
}
```

1. if the screen resolution is 1600*1200, will the div's width be 25% of the screen in the browser ?
2. if the screen resolution is 4000*2400, will the div's width be 10% of the screen in the browser ?

I want to be always 25%.

If I use percent to set the width, `div` will shrink automatically when browser is not in full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out use % instead of px. % are more responsive and will adjust to any screen resolution

```
.a{
  width: 40%;
  height: 60%; 
}
```

Comment: If use this way,`div` will be smaller, when browser was no in full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of px or % , the best practice is to Use the following units to make your div or any elements responsive on the basis of screen size as they target the "viewport" .
Viewport Width (vw) Viewport Height (vh) — This unit is based on the height of the viewport. A value of 1vh is equal to 1% of the viewport height. Viewport Width (vw) — This unit is based on the width of the viewport. A value of 1vw is equal to 1% of the viewport width.
for example
  width: 40vw;
  height: 60vh;

This will fix your problem. You can use this unit while defining size of your fonts as well.

Comment: This may help you ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551606/why-does-vw-include-the-scrollbar-as-part-of-the-viewport